# Make a python discord bot leave a specific guild with the event "on_guild_join"

Tags: python, discord.py

Simple.
Just want to make a bot leave a guild with the `on_guild_join` event, based on the guild id.

Here's my code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    server1 = 'my discord guild id goes here'

    if guild.id == server1:
        try:
            guild_to_leave = bot.get_guild(server1)
            await guild_to_leave.leave()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

I tried it but the command didn't work. It does not show any errors, but I want to solve this error.
Thanks for your help.

**CHANGE**

My error was that the variable "server1" was not an int. When I transformed it into an int, the event worked.

Comment: Have you tested if the guild.id in question is the same as the server1 variable?

Comment: your server1 variable should be integer first of all.

Comment: Transforming server1 variable into an int worked for me, thanks.